# How to delete a random element from a deque

Tags: c++, object, visual-c++, element, deque

In my project I am using the stl library with a deque of objects. The program is supposed delete certain object varibles meet a condition, but every time an element meets the requierments to be deleted the program has to abort. here is a simplified version of my program

```
int main(){
    deque<Cars> card;
    deque<Cars> iterator::iter
    int count=0;
    Cars car(14,15);
    card.push_front(car);
    Cars car(12,45);
    card.push_front(car);
    Cars car(15,60);
    card.push_front(car);
    Cars car(20,45)
    card.push_front(car);
    for(iter=card.begin();iter!=card.end();iter++){
        if(iter->getnum2()==60){
            card.erase(card.begin()+count);

        }
        count=count+1;

    }
    return 0;

}
```

Pleas note  **I have to use a deque in this** and in this example the getnum2 that I'm making the iter get applies to the 2nd number for each of the car objects I made.

Comment: Use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Erase-Remove) instead of erasing elements from the container while you're iterating over them.

Comment: Answer dropped because not only is the presented code not valid, it also doesn't match the question in the *title*. There is no attempt at garnering a random element, though there is at least one for deleting matching elements to some precondition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
for ( iter = card.begin(); iter != card.end() ; )
     (iter->getnum2() == 60) ? iter = card.erase(iter) : ++iter;
```